# regexp contain æøåÆØÅ also

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How can i edit this to also accept æøåÆØÅ?

```
function validate_username($input, $pattern = '/[^A-Za-z0-9]/')
{
     return !preg_match($pattern, $input);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
'/[^A-Za-z0-9æøåÆØÅ]/u'
```

Requires that your php file is saved in UTF-8 and also that the input is UTF-8 as well of course.

Comment: UTF-8 is not required; would also work with any other character set/encoding containing these characters.

Comment: @Gumbo Only if you remove the `u`-flag. With `u`-flag it must be UTF-8, the pattern won't compile if there are invalid UTF-8 bytes and `u`-flag.

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate_username($input, $pattern = '/^\w+$/')
{
     return preg_match($pattern, $input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
'/[^\p{L}\d]/u'
```

`\p{L}` matches all unicode letters, including those that you have already listed and lots of those that haven't caused a trouble for you yet, but may cause some day.

`\d` also matches all digits including unicode ones in different scripts.

Comment: You need the `u` flag for this to work.